# Why isn't Telnet enabled by default in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, telnet

When I pinged my mailserver from the command prompt using:

```
telnet mail.mydomain.com 25
```

I got the error `Telnet is not a recognized command`. I looked for a workaround and then found that Telnet was unchecked by default in Windows. Once i checked it, it started working.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but I heard it was something to do with security.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TELNET communicates with the peer (telnet server) in clear text.
This is a security hazard compared to say the SSH connect. 
To this end, the telnet client on windows is disabled by default. 
This often comes as a surprise and [many sites describe the steps to get it working](http://www.webtlk.com/2009/07/24/how-to-enable-telnet-in-windows-vista-and-windows-7/),
you seem to have found them already :)

For normal purposes, it would be a better option to use SSH ([PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) if you want to connect *to* a Windows machine).

Comment: My favorite part is that they disabled telnet and didn't give me ssh. D:

Answer (score 5):

When wanting to query in clear text an SMTP server, to my knowledge, there isn't any simpler way to do it than Telnet. [SSH can't be used for this]

In this case I advise you to [enable telnet](http://www.webtlk.com/2009/07/24/how-to-enable-telnet-in-windows-vista-and-windows-7/) or to use something like [SMTPDiag](http://www.whitepeaksoftware.com/main/smtp-diagnostics).

Comment: @simtris, I appreciate the ease of working with TELNET to talk with an SMTP server. I also agree that enabling TELNET is a good idea to connect with the SMTP server as the OP wants to. I see the question as a query on the reasons for something as simple as the telnet client needing to be enabled. Do you see a different question or think my answer deviates from the point in discussion?

Comment: @nik : U right, his question was about the "disapearance" of the telnet client. You anwer the part "security", I addead the part "usefull" :)

Comment: @simtris, fair enough :)

Comment: Since this question was referenced recently by answers to other questions, I have edited this answer to remove commentary on other answers (it's author lacked rep to make comments at the time).