# Is there a telnet utility for windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, telnet

Is there a simple telnet command line utility for Windows 7?  I am used to the telnet command that is built into UNIX, but I can't seem to find one for Windows that can be used similarly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Telnet client in Windows 7 is disabled by default, and needs to be enabled via Windows' Programs and Features:

Control Panel --> Programs --> Turn Windows features on or off, in the dialog that pops up check-mark "Telnet Client".

For more info see: [Why isn't Telnet enabled by default in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/110760/why-isnt-telnet-enabled-by-default-in-windows-7)

And at MS's site you can check out [Telnet: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Telnet-frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: For windows server its under 'add roles and features wizard'

Answer (score 20):

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is a free implementation of Telnet and SSH for Windows and Unix. Download the latest [PuTTy for telnet](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttytel.exe).

Comment: +1 PuTTY is much better than the built-in telnet

Comment: While PuTTY is useful, and can serve the purpose well, What is needed, as stated above, is a utility that allows me to connect directly from the command line, rather than having to run a GUI.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to test a network connection, you can use with **Powershell** :

```
Test-NetConnection google.com -port 80
```

Comment: nice alternative +1

Answer (score 3):

A much better (and FOSS) Telnet client is [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.GreenEnd.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to connect using telnet from the command line, take a look at [Plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Its by the same people that make PuTTY. Plink allows you to script connections to anything PuTTY can connect to. I used plink with simple batch files and perl files on windows with fairly good results (of course you results may vary). If you are just looking to get a telnet connection from command line then the vanilla telnet client in Windows should be okay.