# Windows Vista Is there a Telnet Command available on command line cmd?

Tags: windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a telnet utility for windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/349080/is-there-a-telnet-utility-for-windows)

I need to run a telnet session of Windows vista.  Is there is telnet command application that I can run from cmd line?  where would I find this executable?  If not what should I install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Telnet-frequently-asked-questions

Telnet is available, but is not installed by default.  You can install it be going under Control Panel/ Programs and Features/ Windows Features.

It will be available under Telnet Client.